# What's the bottleneck in my geth sync?

Tags: synchronization

I've been running geth for about 2.5 days so far, and I'm trying to work out why it's taking so long to sync.

It's downloaded ~40Gb of the blockchain (up to block #2379173 if I'm interpreting the output correctly) and is running at consistently <25% CPU, often less. The IO load varies a lot but is on the order of 5-10MB/s, if that was purely for downloading and writing the blockchain data, it would take about half a day, rough estimate. This implies that the IO load is *not* for writing the chain to the disk. The network load is tens of KB/s, and my connection can handle a lot more than that. This means there's some MB/s of IO (writing) which is neither network chatter nor a net disk write.

The bottleneck clearly isn't the CPU, and the these numbers don't support IO as the bottleneck either. So why is it taking so long?

Comment: what is command line you used to start geth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your disk a spinning, magnetic disk (as opposed to an SSD)? If so, your disk might be the bottleneck: syncing the blockchain involves a lot of random reads and writes. If your OS supports it, you can check your disk I/O depth queue and/or percent utilization.